# Несколько Checkbox

Tags: php, html

Вопрос про Checkbox. 
Как отметить несколько галочек и занести их значения в бд, все выбранные в одну ячейку?
Ведь добавляется только первое значение.

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="den" value="Понедельник" id="CheckboxGroup1_0" />
  Понедельник</label>
<br />
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="den" value="Вторник" id="CheckboxGroup1_1" />
  Вторник</label>
<br />
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="den" value="Суббота" id="CheckboxGroup1_2" />
  Суббота</label>
```

.

```
 $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO students (den) VALUES ('$den')");
    if ($result == 'true') {echo "Добавлен!";}
    else {echo "НЕТ!";}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сервер получает массив den[], чтобы записать все значения в одну ячейку, надо их конкатенировать перед вставкой, например, так:

```
$joined_den = join(",", $den);
```

Answer (score 6):

Назовите кнопки не den, а den[], тогда в пришедшем $den получите массив значений, их поочереди и добавляйте (foreach).